# How to directly show $S=\sum_{k=1}^{m}e^{2\pi ik^2/m}=\sqrt{m}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^{m}e^{2\pi ik^2/m}$,if $m$ is odd,how to directly calculate the absolute value of $S=\sqrt{m}$.Don't use Gauss sum since here it says "it's easily shown"[image]

My try is as follows:
$$ \begin{align}S^2&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}e^{2\pi ik^2/m}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m}e^{-2\pi ik^2/m}\right)
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\sum_{d=1}^{m-k}2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}(2dk+k^2)\right)+m\end{align}$$
we must prove $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\sum_{d=1}^{m-k}2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{m}(2dk+k^2))=0$.If m is small, I can directly calculate, but if m is large, how to do so by induction or any other solutions.

Comment: How did the $\pi$ disappear in the last equality?

Comment: Sorry,I missed something,now it seems right

Comment: Is the $\frac{2\pi}{m}$ in or outside the cosine function input?

Comment: Is it "$2\cdot\frac{2\pi}{m}\cdot\cos(2dk+k^2)$" or something else?

Comment: I think $S=m$ using $e^{2\pi i}=1$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Because fix k,we only need to consider numbers that is larger than k by symmetry

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but the inner sum is just the real part of a geometric series, so you can probably evaluate the inner sum that way.

Comment: Why is one term in the product the conjugate of the other? Is it obvious that $S$ is real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
|S|^2
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{l=0}^{m-1} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{m}(l^2-k^2)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{d=0}^{m-1} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{m}(2kd+d^2)\right) \tag{$l\equiv k+d \pmod{m}$} \\
&= \sum_{d=0}^{m-1} \Biggl[ \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \exp\left(\frac{4\pi i d}{m} k\right) \Biggr] \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i d^2}{m}\right).
\end{align*}

As pointed out by @Cade Reinberger, the geometric sum formula shows that the inner sum only survives with the value $m$ when $d=0$, and hence the desired claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $$\sum_{n=1}^L \cos(a+nd) = \csc\left(\frac d2 \right) \sin\left(\frac{dL}{2} \right) \cos\left(a+\frac d2(L+1)\right), $$ the inner sum can be evaluated exactly to reduce it down to $$- 2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \cot\left(\frac{2\pi k}{m} \right ) \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k^2}{m} \right)$$ Then it can be easily shown that $$  \cot\left(\frac{2\pi k}{m} \right ) \sin\left(\frac{2\pi k^2}{m} \right) $$ changes sign under the transformation $k \mapsto m-k$, and hence this sum is equal to the negative of itself, or in other words equals $0$.

Comment: Thank you all the same,but someone seems ahead of you and I can only choose one

Comment: @math No problem, but ahead as in what aspect?

Comment: @Tavish.Time or post position

Comment: @math Right, okay.